# Can logic be traced back to neurons?

Tags: neuroscience

In our everyday experience, and in both math and philosophy particularly, there exist some binary order in the sense that some statements can be classified as true or false.

Does this have a specific neural correlation in the brain (classifying a statement as either true or false)? Or in other words, is it possible to correlate the process of assigning true/false with some particular feature of the brain?

Comment: I edited the question based on your comments on [user20582's answer](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/20967/21). I feel this somewhat clarifies what you mean by 'classifying as true/false'. However, your question is still lacking initial research and might potentially be closed as [not framed in psychology or neuroscience](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience).

Comment: To elaborate: from a [materialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialism) perspective, certainly the answer is **yes**, "logic can be traced back to neurons", but I presume that does not answer your question. Instead, your question seems to be whether the process (e.g., neural pathways) of concluding that a given statement is true or false is similar across individuals and individual statements. I hope this clarifies why you did not receive the answer you wanted, as your question (still) leaves open too many factors to the interpretation of whoever answers.

Comment: @StevenJeuris yes that's exactly what I mean...Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly some statements are either true or false. Either it rains or it doesn't. But when you think about many of these statements more carefully, the truth of these statements isn't really binary at all, or the binary fact is largely irrelevant.

Using the weather example, for most people it is not very helpful to know that it doesn't rain when there is a hurricane or it's snowing, both of which wouldn't usually be considered "not rain" by someone who wants to know what to wear. So the answer to "Does it rain?" usually isn't "No", but, for example, "You should take your umbrella because it looks like it might rain later".

The brain also isn't binary. Axons do not either forward an electrical impulse or not, but impulses of different intensities or frequencies. Neurons are often not activated by impulses from a single synapse, but usually by multiple synapses. Synapses do not either send out transmitters or not, but different amounts of them. Functions aren't located in one area, but in multiple areas. And so on.

Logic and maths (and psychological theories) are *simplifications* of a very complex reality. They provide simple solutions that often work (because life is flexible enough to adapt to a rigid approach), but just as often logic or mathematical (or psychological) approaches to deal with real problems are destined to fail.

Comment: @schopenhauer, from what i got from the question, the third paragraph kind of gives details on what you asked. If this isn't what you were looking for, can you explain why.

Comment: I agree with JohnyTKoshy (+1). This is a suitable (initial) answer to an overly broad ill-founded question. Anything beyond this could fill books (and then we would have to close the question as too broad). It would help, @Schopenhauer, if you could clarify what _it is_ that you are asking. Or, how is it that "The brain isn't binary" does not give you an initial answer? It seems like you might want to elaborate on what you call _"some binary order in the sense that some statements are true or false"_. user20582 did a good job at rebutting that here.

Comment: I agree that an answer doesn't have to be *the* answer in case of such broad questions. If you could add some credible sources I'm happy to upvote this.

Comment: @Schopenhauer please be kind to people going through an effort of answering your post.

Comment: @AliceD I know I've been rude. But just read the first sentence. It's really annoying. I'm not saying that reality is binary; I'm saying 'Once we know that many statements are clasified as T or F in our brain: does it have a specific neural correlation?'